# distribute private key with application?

Tags: security, encryption, public-key-encryption

I'm building an application and want it to securely transfer data to a server.
Thinking to use public/private keys for initial handshake to encrypt a key with which to encrypt subsequent data.

Is it reasonable to have the private key integrated in the executable which will be distributed out in the wild for anyone to reverse-engineer?
I also thought of using three-pass protocol, but read about some of its weaknesses and it probably won't work for me

Comment: This question should be asked on security.stackexchange.com

Comment: frankly, i don't understand the stackexchange mess. post this here, that there - what's the use of tags/keywords then? may be the site itself should offer where to place the question based on tags?

Comment: Because StackOverflow is about helping you solve a problem in your code (which I don't see here). Even if this question may be on topic here, it might best suit Security.stackExchange.com because you will have more security expert there. You are asking for a way to secure your data... I know it isn't always easy to know where to post...

Comment: Can you just use TLS instead?

Comment: @1615903 the plan is for additional encryption on top of https

Comment: Why? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: make the data hard to get :)
will be using https, but i want an extra layer of security for the data that moves over the wire (and please don't discourage me by saying https is a strong enough protection)

Comment: This sounds like a massive waste of time.  To be frank, and not to be rude, the fact that you need to ask this question means that your final solution won't be secure anyway, not to mention it's completely pointless since you are channeling through TLS.

Comment: @LukePark nothing is truly secure this days; the requirement is for an additional layer; apparently even an armored limo cannot protect you from a determined psycho

Comment: @estoy I feel like your unfamiliarity with this particular area of programming might be inhibiting you from understanding why what you want to do is superfluous.  Just something to consider.

Comment: @LukePark, I'm thankful for your concern and advice, but a requirement is a requirement - I hope you understand that; and the solution below is the one that seems to best fulfill the requirement

Comment: @estoy Out of curiosity, is it your requirement or a clients requirement?  And if the client, are they technical?

Comment: @LukePark i thought it was apparent it is a client requirement; cannot comment on their technical expertise, but cannot blame them if they want extra privacy for their data, as redundant as required

Answer (score 0):

I followed Martin's advice and posted to security exchange (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158650/distribute-private-key-with-application).
There I received an answer that I accepted, by user Serverfrog:

> Generate the Private/Public Keypair on the client, encrypt this with a
>   password (maybe choose from the User itself).
>
> The send the Public Key encrypted via Server Public Key to the Server
>   and you have your entire Public/Private Stack.